# Laravel: How validate a field of not related table

Tags: laravel

**Problem:** A user can be edited. A user is subject to a area and this area can be of a different category (`1: cat_a, 2: cat_b, 3: cat_c`). A new requirement is that areas may no longer be assigned to the category C (`cat_c`).

```
Tables: 
users: id, name
areas: id, area_name, responsible_id 
Categories: id, area_name, cat_name, permissions
```

The request contains the key areas with an array of categorie_ids. (`[1,2,3]`).

```php
public function rules()
{
    $userId = $this->route('user');
    $roles = User::listRoles();
        return [
            'areas.*' => 'exists:area,id',
        ];
}
```

**Question:** Is there a Laravel validation to check a not related table to users ("`areas`"), and if it is category 3, return a fail?

```
Request example request:
 [1,2,3]: should fail
 [1,2]: should pass validation
```

Comment: simply use the `not_in`  rule : `exists:area,id|not_in:3`. See https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#rule-not-in

Comment: @Lk77 I will try and give you in view moments a feedback...

Comment: there is no such ruie as a `not_exists` so you will need to retrieve the banned ids from the table and use the `not_in` rule : `Rule::notIn(BannedCategories::pluck('id)),`

Comment: @Lk77 hi, sorry. unfortunately I didn't really understand what exactly you meant by your last comment.

Comment: i mean that there is no rule to do exactly what you want, aka check the database for the absence of a row, you will need to retrieve the ids that are banned and use the not_in rule.